# How to resize images in wordpress which are not in wp tables

Tags: wordpress

is there some native WP function to resize my image?
what i have is a url.
i used this function:

```
image_resize($options_global['global_favicon'], 16, 16, true);
```

but it gave me error:

> no encode delegate for this image format `//domain.cz/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/18175-
>   16x16.jpg' @ constitute.c/WriteImage/1149

Answer (score 0):

Try to bellow function for image resize.

```
 <?php image_resize_dimensions( $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_resize_dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_get_image_editor( $path, $args )
for. ex.

```
   $image = wp_get_image_editor( 'cool_image.jpg' );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
     $image->rotate( 90 );
     $image->resize( 300, 300, true );
     $image->save( 'new_image.jpg' );
  }
```

full ref. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor